# Excel conversion of text containing ranges--numeric to alpha-numeric

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to convert a range of numbers (and single digits) from a number-only format to alpha-numeric format.  Entire statement is in a single, excel cell and would like the converted version to be in a neighboring cell.

As an example:

```
Assuming 1-24=B1-B24

Assuming 25-48=C1-C24
```

INPUT—

```
 screen 1-3,5,7-9,11-30,32-37,39-40,41,44-46
```

DESIRED OUTPUT (all acceptable)

```
   screen B1-B3,B5,B7-B9,B11-C6,C8-C13,C15-C16,C17,C20-C22
```

OR

```
 screen B1-B3,B5,B7-B9,B11-B24,C1-C6,C8-C13,C15-C16,C17,C20-C22
```

OR

```
 screen B1-B3,B5,B7-B9,B11-B24

   screen C1-C6,C8-C13,C15-C16,C17,C20-C22
```

Using excel functions is proving quite cumbersome so excel macro would be better.  I've looked for examples of requested conversion but haven't found anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Bob

Comment: This is quite convoluted.  Perhaps you can post a screenshot of what you're trying to do?  What have you tried so far? What's worked, or hasn't?

Comment: BW, I'm trying to convert the text string to change the numbers and add the "B" or "C" value depending on the original digit.

Comment: BW, I'm trying to convert the text string to change the numbers and add the "B" or "C" value depending on the original digit.  Very simple example woul be: any value from 1-24 stays the same and gets B appended to it.  Any value from 25-48 gets 24 subtracted from it and gets a "C" appended to it.  Ex: 20-28 would become B20-C4.  I can do this with excel functions using the "," and "-" as delimiters then massaging data but it is clumsy and difficult to do with multiple ranges in same string.  So (1-3,5,7-9,11-30,32-37) would become (B1-B3,B5,B7-B9,B11-C6,C8-C13).  Could use help with macro.

Comment: I think I get it. The only thing I'm really unclear on is what, *exactly*, does your cells with data look like so I can see how to formulate the ...formula.

Answer (score 1):

Hey here is a solution that i tested out.  Not sure if "screen" needs to be in the string or not.  Let me know and I will tweak it if that's the case.

Its a user defined function.  So drop this vba in a module and then go to a worksheet and type in "=AlphaConvert(" + the cell reference.

Assumption here is that only one cell will be referenced at a time.

Last this could easily be converted to a sub routine and probably run a bit faster than the function.

```
Public Function AlphaConvert(TargetCell As Range)
    Dim v       As Long
    Dim vArr()  As String
    Dim i       As Long
    Dim iArr()  As String
    Dim a       As String

    vArr = Split(TargetCell.Value, ",")

    For v = LBound(vArr) To UBound(vArr)
        If InStr(vArr(v), "-") > 0 Then
            iArr = Split(vArr(v), "-")

            For i = LBound(iArr) To UBound(iArr)
                If i = LBound(iArr) Then
                    a = AlphaCode(iArr(i))
                Else
                    a = a & "-" & AlphaCode(iArr(i))
                End If
            Next i

            vArr(v) = a
        Else
            vArr(v) = AlphaCode(vArr(v))
        End If

        If v = LBound(vArr) Then
            AlphaConvert = vArr(v)
        Else
            AlphaConvert = AlphaConvert & "," & vArr(v)
        End If
    Next v
End Function

Private Function AlphaCode(Nbr As Variant)
    Select Case Nbr
        Case 1 To 24
            AlphaCode = "B" & Nbr
        Case Else
            AlphaCode = "C" & Nbr - 24
    End Select
End Function
```